# Biblatex APA6 not getting parentheses in year of in-text citation

Tags: biblatex, citing, apa-style

I'm using Biblatex package and when citing in-text, i.e. `\cite{...}` and it renders the year following author's last name without the parentheses in the year, e.g. `\cite{einstein}` renders as "Einstein 1905". And as long as I know, APA 6th edition rules in-text citations with parentheses, i.e. it should be "Einstein (1905)".

I'd be thankful if you could guide me in what is missing in the apa6 setup in Biblatex, and even if this mentioned package is reliable in terms of citing with APA for a journal article.

Thanks!

I attach my main.tex and sample.bib files and output:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

% Sets-up bibtex for APA 6th
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{sample.bib} % Imports bibliography file

\title{Template}
\author{Author}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{First section}

Items that are cited: \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}, The Einstein's journal paper \cite{einstein} and the Dirac's book \cite{dirac} are physics related items. Next, a citation about \textit{The \LaTeX\ Companion} book \cite{latexcompanion}.

\medskip

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

```
@article{einstein,
  author =       "Albert Einstein",
  title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
                 [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
  journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
  volume =       "322",
  number =       "10",
  pages =        "891--921",
  year =         "1905",
  DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004",
  keywords =     "physics"
}

@book{dirac,
  title={The Principles of Quantum Mechanics},
  author={Paul Adrien Maurice Dirac},
  isbn={9780198520115},
  series={International series of monographs on physics},
  year={1981},
  publisher={Clarendon Press},
  keywords = {physics}
}

@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
 
@online{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/~uno/abcde.html",
    keywords  = "latex,knuth"
}

@inbook{knuth-fa,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   title = "Fundamental Algorithms",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   year = "1973",
   chapter = "1.2",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@book{knuth-acp,
   author = "Donald E. Knuth",
   publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
   title = "The Art of Computer Programming",
   series = "Four volumes",
   year = "1968",
   note = "Seven volumes planned",
   keywords  = "knuth,programming"
}

@article{ctan,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351",
    keywords  = "latex"
}
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard citation commands in author/year styles in `biblatex` are `\textcite` which yields *Author (year)*   and `\parencite` which yields *(Author, year)*. Depending on the style `\cite` is supported but aliased to one of the other citation commands. In the case of `apa` it's aliased to a version of `\parencite` but without the parentheses.

So instead of `\cite` you should use `\textcite`.  For strings of references inside parentheses you should use `\parencite` which properly will remove the parentheses around the year when the citation itself is inside parentheses.

Also, at date of writing this answer, `style=apa` implements the APA 7th edition; to get conforming APA 6th edition style, use `style=apa6`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Also, I'd be grateful if you could tell me whether I can rely on Biblatex in implementing strictly the citation styles, in other words if using correctly Biblatex for a paper and sending it to a peer-reviewed journal, I can expect not to have any problem regarding the citation style.

Comment: @nrivera Well there's no guarantee, but `biblatex-apa` is actively maintained, so I think it's pretty faithful to the style. And no journal will reject your paper for bibliography formatting issues unless you're really not following their style at all.